# Do all Contracts implement some abstract base Contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I've deployed a very simple Contract to Testnet. It has the following function...

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public
{
    /* Check if sender has balance and for overflows */
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value && balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);

    /* Add and subtract new balances */
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;

    /* Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place */
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
}
```

Question: Does the standard Ethereum wallet actually call onto this function when I use the wallet to send my token, e.g., with this code am I implementing an abstract function that is declared in some base Contract? If yes, where can I look at the base Contract declaration? If no, how does the standard Ethereum wallet know how to transfer my tokens? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the standard Ethereum wallet," but no, there is no base contract that all contracts inherit from.

Tokens like this work by implementing a standard known as [ERC20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md), which nearly all tools for viewing and transferring tokens understand and consume.

Comment: By that I meant the Ethereum wallet that is included in Mist and linked to for download from the Ethereum website. But I think I understand now. Thanks very much.

Comment: Ah, yes, I assume that Mist has built-in understanding/support for ERC20 tokens.